# Como puedo hacer que cada vez que le de al boton "agregar" ingrese lo que tienen los inputs a la tabla, y que los inputs queden vacios?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
                    <h1 id="titulo">
                        Proyecto final
                    </h1>

</head>

<body>

        <script>

    function sum() {
        var primer_numero = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var segundo_numero = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
        var result = parseInt(primer_numero) * parseInt(segundo_numero);
        var itbs = result *0.18;


        if (!isNaN(result) && !isNaN(itbs) ){
             document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
             document.getElementById('txt4').value = itbs;
        }
    }

function obtenerdatos(){
    var nom_p = document.getElementById('txt0').value;
    var cant = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var precio = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    var resultado = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
    var itbs = document.getElementById('txt4').value;

    document.mi_formulario.nom_producto.value = nom_p;
    document.mi_formulario.can_obtenida.value = cant;
    document.mi_formulario.precio.value = precio;
    document.mi_formulario.resultado.value = resultado;
    document.mi_formulario.itbs.value = itbs;
}

        </script>

<section>
    <form name="mi_formulario" id="mi:formulario" method="get" autocomplete="on">

<input type="text" id="txt0" placeholder="Nombre del producto" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="Cantidad" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" placeholder="Precio" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input type="text" id="txt3" onkeyup="sum();" placeholder="Resultado" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt4" onkeyup="sum();" placeholder="itbs" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="button" name="btn1" value="Agregar" onclick="obtenerdatos()" id="boton" autofocus="autofocus">




    <table border="1" id="tabla">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="nom_producto" id="nom_producto"  id="nom"</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="can_obtenida" id="can_obtenida" id="can"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" id="precio"</td>   
        <td><input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" id="resul"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="itbs" id="itbs" id="itbs" </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
 <!--       <td><input type="text" name="nom_producto" id="nom_producto"  id="nom"</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="can_obtenida" id="can_obtenida" id="can"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" id="precio"</td>   
        <td><input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" id="resul"</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="itbs" id="itbs" id="itbs" </td>
-->
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>

</section>  
    <h1 id="nom_p">Nom. Producto</h1>
    <h1 id="can">Cantidad</h1>
    <h1 id="pre">Precio</h1>
    <h1 id="resul">Resultado</h1>
    <h1 id="itbs">ITBS</h1>

<script>
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar más td a tu tabla puedes usar esta forma.

```
 $("#tabla").append(`tus td que desees agregar`);
    //
    $("#txt1").val('');
    $("#txt2").val('');
```

Pero si quieres sumar lo que tiene tus inputs de la tabla te recomendaria usar arreglos :

```
var datatemp = [];
funcion agregar(){
  datatemp.push({
      "id":id,
      "producto":producto
    });

generarTabla();
}

function generarTabla(){
 for(int i =0 ;i < datatemp.length ; i++){
    $("#tabla").append(`tus td que desees agregar`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo para  responder, para la proxima añado la explicacion.